# MongoDB - NodeJS - Mongoose Slow Query Array

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a question about Mongo and NodeJS currently in one project that i am working on have some issues with the performance. It does work but has a mix of ideas as far as i see. I would like to see some ideas from a more experience person.

I will share the flow with you and the used libs and tools on the way i try to understand it there days and as far as i see might be a better way to do it but still will be slow and un-efficient.

Used Tools and Lib: lodash, mongoose, async, and more.

This is what is the results from NewRelic:

- Database MongoDB preferences toArray 19.8    13.6    423ms
- Database MongoDB spotifies toArray   19.4    12.6    415ms
- Database MongoDB mifi toArray    19.2    12.6    409ms
- Database MongoDB fifi toArray    18.9    12.6    404ms
- Database MongoDB locations toArray   14.3    18.5    305ms

A sample of what is used to add to the model all the time:

```
const subObjectsOutCards = [{
name : 'preferencesModel',
model : 'Preferences'}, {
name : 'spotifyModel',
model : 'Spotify'} ,{
name : 'MifiModel',
model : 'mifi'}, {
name : 'fiModel', 
model : 'Fifi'}];
```

Next One:

```
exports.fetchUsers = (callback) => {
Account.find().populate('userTrips').exec((err, docs) => {
    if (_.isEmpty(docs)){
        callback(null, null)
    } else {
        async.map(docs, (doc, callback) => {
            var object = doc.toObject();
            exports.fetchSubObjectsToUserForCards(object, doc._id, (result) => {
                callback(null, result);
            })
        }, (err, results1) => {
            var updatedAccounts = results1; 
            async.map(updatedAccounts, (doc, callback) => {
                locationController.getMostRecentLocationById(doc._id, (result) => {
                    var updatedDoc = doc;
                    updatedDoc.locationModel = result;
                    callback(null, updatedDoc);
                })
            }, (err, results2) => {
                callback(results2);
            })
        })
    }
})}
```

This is where it goes after:

```
exports.fetchObjectSub = (account, userId, callback) => {
var newAccount = account;
var itemsProcessed = 0;
subObjectsOut.forEach(function(object){
    mongoose.model(object.model).find({'accountId' : userId}, function(err, doc){
        if (err){
            callback(false);
        } else {
            if (!_.isNil(doc[0]) && newAccount !== false){
                doc = doc[0].toObject();
                newAccount[object.name] = doc;
                itemsProcessed++;
                if (itemsProcessed === subObjectsOut.length){
                    callback(newAccount);
                }
            } else {
                itemsProcessed++;
            }
        }
    });
});}
```

Account Example:

```
{
"_id": "59f372389f89d1cb0dbabdbad",
"residence": "Katowice, Poland",
"orientation": "Bisexual",
"lastName": "Kowalczyk",
"job": "Web Developer @ Freelance",
"gender": "Female",
"firstName": "Marina",
"dob": "7/10/1998",
"about": "Computer science student",
"lastConnection": "2017-11-24T19:16:28.780Z",
"created_at": "2017-10-27T20:55:06.070Z",
"phone": {
    "number": "7183173136"
},
"profilePicture": {
    "url": "https://.JPG",
    "pictureType": ".JPG"
},
"interests": [
    "Sports",
    "Food",
    "Cycling",
    "Running",
    "Cooking",
    "Movies",
    "Fashion",
    "Business",
    "Travel",
    "Music",
    "Theatre",
    "Yoga",
    "Party",
    "Dancing",
    "Reading"
],
"__v": 38}
```

Preferences Example:

```
{
"_id": "59a83258c7fd5b4ae586c53b",
"visibilityLocation": true,
"visibilityGenderPreferences": true,
"visibilityFb": false,
"visibilityDistance": false,
"visibilityAge": false,
"showMyProfileAs": "Male",
"showMe": "Males",
"locationAccuracy": 0,
"accountId": "59f372389f89d1cb0dbabdbad",
"created_at": "2017-08-31T13:29:42.462Z",
"distance": {
    "max": 30,
    "metrics": "K",
    "min": 0
},
"ageRange": {
    "max": 32,
    "min": 18
},
"__v": 0}
```

EDIT: As requested

1. Indexes - automatic from the system on the _id
2. Index on accountId in each table from the main one
3. Operation Performed is on 1000 elements and its really slow: Speeds that i get are 3000ms to 9000ms and all the slow down on average says 5M ms for these documents which is insane....
4. Example Account and Preferences can be found above before edit.

When i started with this i thought straight that are the filters that we have but seems its not the case. Since thats pretty fast. Problems comes from here and the tools confirm it.

The idea about the structure of the Schema as far as i see is to be a flat one and after to be used Collections all the time instead of references of the other tables. And for each one since there are a lot filters there need to be a search for each person on each one of their five tables and getting their account on the way and adding for each table a field with it and creating a documents. And all of them wait for each other all the time. So if you have 5 users = 5 new documents and after for each there was a loop and a new documents. Please if anybody can help a bit with this would be great. Thanks you

Comment: What you sample document from DB look like? How many docs you have? What indexes are created on this collection?

Comment: I already edited. Thanks for reaching out.

Comment: Looking at the code I'd look for the issue in the mapping code - async is very slow on multiple asynchronous callbacks.